# Emit Event Form Servers To All Clients

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have this  very basic script `app.js` at server-side:

```
const {app, apiEvents}    = require('./server.js');
const http   = require('http');
const server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(8080);
const io     = require('socket.io').listen(server); 
function connected(socket) { 
    console.log('a user connected');  
}
apiEvents.on('db-event', (data) => {
    console.log(`Received event:%s`,data);
    io.emit ('update', msg); 
}); 

io.sockets.on('connection',(socket) => {connected(socket);});
```

This is the client-side:

```
// Test client
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080',(socket) => {

});

socket.on('connect', function(){        
    socket.on ('update', function (msg) {
        console.log (msg);
    });

});
```

The `server.js` is just a wrapper for a basic route in express. When I connect to `localhost:8080:/api` a db-event is fired.

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express     = require('express');
const path        = require('path');

//const logger = require('morgan');
const { apiRouter, apiEvents} = require('./routes/api');

const app = express(); 

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
}); 
module.exports = {app, apiEvents};
```

This is `routes/api.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
const apiEvents = new EventEmitter();
const apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Received query%s",req.query);
    res.sendStatus(200);
    apiEvents.emit('db-event',req.query);
  });

module.exports = {apiRouter, apiEvents};
```

When I make `curl http://localhost:8080/api\?operation=pippo`
I see the logs at server:

```
Received query { operation:'pippo' }
Received event:{ operation: 'message', user: 'pippo' }
```

but at client-side nothing is written out. Why?

Comment: where is `msg` defined in `apiEvents.on('db-event', (data) => {console.log(`Received event:%s`,data);io.emit ('update', msg); }); `

Comment: THANK YOU! That was the stupid error! I will delete the question...